# Text view up when keyboard appears swift

Tags: swift, uitableview, textview, keyboard, uitextfield

I have textField and textView in the table. When editing textFiled, this code works and all text fields rise above the keyboard. When I edit a textView, nothing happens. It will help to edit the code so that for textView this code also works. Please do not offer third-party libraries. Thanks

```
 override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(
            self,
            selector: #selector(keyboardWillShow(_:)),
            name: UIResponder.keyboardWillShowNotification,
            object: nil)
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(
            self,
            selector: #selector(keyboardWillHide(_:)),
            name: UIResponder.keyboardWillHideNotification,
            object: nil)
    }
    
    override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillDisappear(animated)
        
        NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self)
    }
        
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
   
       
    }
        @objc
        fileprivate func keyboardWillShow(_ notification: Notification) {
            let keyboardFrame = ((notification as NSNotification).userInfo?[UIResponder.keyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as? NSValue)?.cgRectValue ?? CGRect.zero
            
            let contentInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0.0, left: 0.0, bottom: keyboardFrame.height, right: 0.0)
            self.tableView.contentInset = contentInsets
            self.tableView.scrollIndicatorInsets = contentInsets
            
            UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.25) {
                self.tableView.layoutIfNeeded()
                self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
            }
        }
        
        @objc
        fileprivate func keyboardWillHide(_ notification: Notification) {
            tableView.contentInset = .zero
        }
```

Comment: Dows the keyboard appears? Have you put a breakpoint to check whether the `keyboardWillShow` function gets called or not?

Comment: @Mat Yes, it works. Everything is fine with textField, but there are no results with TextView, I can scroll and then it can be seen, can it scroll over the keyboard itself?

Answer (score -1):

yes you can!
all you need to do is knowing where you textfield position,
then `set your scroll Offset`

write this :

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(yourMethod(_:)), name: UITextField.textDidBeginEditingNotification, object: nil)
```

and your function

```
@objc func yourMethod(_ sender: NSNotification) {
if let tfActive = sender.object as? UITextField {
            let frameRelatedToSuper = tfActive.convert(yourScrollView.contentOffset, to: nil)
            //[mockTF convertPoint:self.parentScrollView.contentOffset toView:nil];
            yourScrollView.setContentOffset(frameRelatedToSuper, animated: true)
        }
    }
```

the rest is your logic.
good luck

note: without adding additional height it might stopped on the top of your textfield
you can declare this

```
var padding: CGFloat = 10
padding = yourTF.bounds.height + padding
frameRelatedToSuper += padding
```

edit : the rest is your logic what i meant was ,because you need to calculate your keyboard height and add to `framerelatedtosuper`